# Does bypassing an ICE trigger Chum's subroutine?

Tags: android-netrunner

If the runner *bypasses* an ICE behind a [Chum](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/chum-core) (subroutine not broken) with [Femme Fatale](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/femme-fatale-core), does Chum's subroutine trigger and deal three netdamage to the runner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have encountered the next ice and so you will take 3 net damage if you don't break its subroutines. As you are bypassing the ice you will not have a chance to break the subroutines and so will take the 3 net damage as soon as the encounter ends.

This is explained the [FAQ From FFG](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)

Comment: So when you *bypass* an ICE you still encounter it? So the *When the runner encounters ...*-abilities (Pop-up window, Data Raven, etc.) still trigger?

Comment: Well all current bypass methods are worded so you encounter the ice before you bypass it. However, the FAQ states under bypass that any unresolved triggered conditional abilities from "When encounters..." the bypassed ice are not resolved. So the Dataraven triggers, but since the Femme is resolved first the DataRaven on encounter is left unresolved.